# How to add in shell script?

Tags: bash, unix

Assume let the value of the variable a be 42,

```
b=18+$a
The value of b should be 60
```

But I'm not getting the value 60. Instead it's printing 18+42.
How can i do it ?

New Query :

```
grep -F "$name" -A1000 filename | sed -n '1p;19p;24p'
```

Assume let a=10,b=20,c=30.In the above grep command can i use '$ap;$bp;$cp' instead of '1p;19p;24p' ?

Another thing, I've given as -A1000. Which implies that starting from 1p it considers till 1000 line , right ? I need to search throughout file without giving the number. Ho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bash:

```
b=$((18+a))
echo "value of b is $b"
```

or

```
let b=18+a
echo "value of b is $b"
```

Comment: @ Prince : Thank U. By the way do u remember this
grep -F "$name" -A37 filename| sed -n '1p;19p;24p' ;which u've guided me yesterday ? In the above command can i mention '$ap;$bp;$cp' instead of '1p;19p;24p' ?

Comment: Inside `$(())` and on the right side of a `let` statement the use of the dollar sign is not required. E.g. `let b=18+a` would work just as well.

Comment: @JackieJames: Variables don't expand inside single-quoted strings. In addition, `bash` would not see "A variable named a followed by the letter p," for example, instead i would see "A variable named ap," which is not what you mean. You should double-quote the expansion and include curly braces for clarity: `"${a}p;${b}p;${c}p"`

Comment: @ Prince :

 grep -F "$name" -A1000 filename | sed -n '1p;19p;24p'

Assume let a=10,b=20,c=30.In the above grep command can i use '$ap;$bp;$cp' instead of '1p;19p;24p' ?

Another thing, I've given as -A1000. Which implies that starting from 1p it considers till 1000 line , right ? I need to search throughout file without giving the number.

Comment: @JackieJames: use double quotes

Comment: grep -F "$name" -A1000 filename | sed -n '1p;19p;24p' 

Another thing, I've given as -A1000. Which implies that starting from 1p it considers till 1000 line , right ? I need to search throughout file without giving the number.

Comment: @JackieJames: ... in the sed portion, use double quotes

Comment: "$ap;$bp;$cp" , right ? giving error as invalid context length argument.

Comment: hw about that 1000 in -A1000 ?

Comment: i didn't get u. Can u plzz be bit specific ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12159/discussion-between-jackie-james-and-prince-john-wesley)

Answer (score 1):

Any mathematical operation in Bash involves the use of $(())

So, for addition, you would do :-

```
b=$((18 + a))
```

Notice that the '$' before a is not required. Some more examples of mathematical operations in Bash are :-

```
a=$((17+1))
b=$((100-a))
c=$((a*b))
d=$((c/b))
echo $((10 * 1024 * 1024)) # Echoes the number bytes in 10 MB
```